# How to solve Fokker-Planck PDE for Brownian particle in square potential driven by periodic time-dependent force

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-pde

**Problem statement:**

We have a Brownian particle in harmonic potential with additional time-dependent force. 
Langevin equation(mass taken to be unit):

$\ddot{x} + \gamma \dot{x} + \omega_0^2 x = \epsilon \cos(\omega t) + \sqrt{2D} \xi(t)$

Corresponding Fokker-Planck equation for $P = P(x,v,t)$, with $v = \dot{x}$:

$\partial_t P = - v\partial_x P + \partial_v(\gamma v + \omega_0^2 x - \epsilon \cos(\omega t)) + D\partial_v^2 P$

**My attempt at solving:**

Perform bilateral Laplace transform on $x$ and $v$. This would lead to 
a differential equation only involving derivatives in $t$. We would solve that and then preform inverse Laplace transform to get back dependency on $x$ and $v$.

The problem is that Laplace transform doesn't get rid entirely of derivatives in $v$ and $x$ since for example

$v\partial_x P \Rightarrow  \hat{x}\partial_{\hat{v}}\hat{P}$

Because of that, we would first have to make some sort of variable substitution:

$y = y(x,v)$

$z = z(x,v)$

and possibly

$F = u(x,v) P (x,v,t)$

which would than lead to PDE without variables as prefactors, sth like:

$\partial_t F = c_1 \partial_x F + c_2(t) \partial_v F+ c_3 F + c_4 \partial_v^2 F$

and then continue as described.